# Can we increase the cache only for local traffic inside the configmap of kubernetes kubedns service?

Tags: kubernetes, kube-dns, coredns

I want to increase the caching limit for traffic coming from within the cluster. for eg if from inside the nginx pod if I do dig to nginx-service then the TTL should be different and if I do dig to google.com then it must be different. Is there any possible way I can achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In the kubernetes plugin section of coreDNS Corefile you can set TTL to set a custom TTL for responses. The default is 5 seconds. The minimum TTL allowed is 0 seconds, and the maximum is capped at 3600 seconds. Setting TTL to 0 will prevent records from being cached.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: coredns
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  Corefile: |
    .:53 {
        errors
        health {
            lameduck 5s
        }
        ready
        kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
            pods insecure
            fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
            ttl 30 # Set this to anything between 0 to 3600
        }
        prometheus :9153
        forward . /etc/resolv.conf
        cache 30
        loop
        reload
        loadbalance
    }
```